# If something increased from 0 to 1 how many percents did it increase?

Tags: percentages

Let's say last month company's profit was 0 dollar this month it's 1 dollar.What percent did the profit increase?

Comment: Infinity... at least

Comment: The relative change in a value is only well-defined if the initial value is not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make sure we understand what we mean by a percent increase. If a company's initial profits are I and it's final profits are F, then our formula for percent profit increase is $100\frac{F-I}{I}$. In this case, with initial profits 0 and final profits 1, then our percent increase is $100\frac{1-0}{0}$, which results in dividing by zero and gives no solution in the reals.